# Use "mailto" on calculated field SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, list, alert

How do I create an automatic alert sent only when a "Reply" field is filled in? "Alert Management" does not answer my question. Can i use the calculated field ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create alert for other users using "Alerts" action of SharePoint.

Alternatively, you can use designer workflow. Everytime item is update/Added the workflow will run to check if "Reply" is filled or empty. If it's filled you can send email using "Send Email"  action in  Workflow

Comment: A workflow is the way to go here - you can also use a hidden column to store the previous contents of the Reply column, and use this to trigger another email if the Reply field is changed.